# What term is used for puzzles that involve finding the correct sequence of mathematical operators?

Tags: puzzle-creation, puzzle-identification

There's a class of puzzles that require the solver to arrange a set of numbers so that they result in a desired outcome by manipulating mathematical operators.  Example:

> Using the numbers [1,3,5,7,9] find an equation that results in 31

which could be solved as

> (9 * 5) - 7 * (3 - 1) = 31

**Is there a specific term for this type of puzzle and if so what is it?**

Comment: It's called sorry-I-had-no-better-idea puzzles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, they are called Operator Search Puzzles.
You can refer to this link: https://brilliant.org/wiki/arithmetic-puzzles-operator-search/

The "24_puzzle" is an extended puzzle of this category.

PS: I am new to SE, so any constructive criticism is much appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to PSE! This is a good answer (+1). Although, you know, just a joke in the comments section would have been ok too here.

Answer (score 1):

On PSE these puzzles are tagged as "formation-of-numbers".